Unexpected concurrency in async method calls in List initialization
I wrote a method that populates a list with objects returned by an asynchronous method.
public async Task<ObjectToReturn> GetObjectToReturnAsync()
{
    var objectToReturn = new ObjectToReturn
    {
        List1 = [
            await AsyncMethod1("A", null),
        ],
        List2 = [
            await AsyncMethod1("B", false),
            await AsyncMethod1("C", false),
            await AsyncMethod1("D", false),
            await AsyncMethod1("E", false),
        ],
        List3 = [
            await AsyncMethod1("B", true),
            await AsyncMethod1("C", true),
            await AsyncMethod1("D", true),
            await AsyncMethod1("E", true),
        ]
    };

    return objectToReturn;
}

private async Task<ObjectInList> AsyncMethod1(string status, bool? reopened)
{
    var total = await repository.GetCountByStatusAsync(status, reopened);

    return new ObjectInList(status, total);
}

and here is the method in the repository
public async Task<int> GetCountByStatusAsync(string status, bool? reopened = null)
{
    var query = context.Table1.AsQueryable();
    
    // if (reopened != null)
    //     query = query.Where(c => c.reopened);

    var count = await query.CountAsync(c => c.status == status);
    
    return count;
}

here the exceution log
[2024-09-06T07:14:02.302Z] Executed DbCommand (51ms) [Parameters=[@__status_0='?'], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
[2024-09-06T07:14:02.303Z] SELECT count(*)::int
[2024-09-06T07:14:02.304Z] FROM schema1.table1 AS c
[2024-09-06T07:14:02.305Z] WHERE c.status = @__status_0
[2024-09-06T07:14:02.312Z] Executed DbCommand (2ms) [Parameters=[@__status_0='?'], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
[2024-09-06T07:14:02.313Z] SELECT count(*)::int
[2024-09-06T07:14:02.314Z] FROM schema1.table1 AS c
[2024-09-06T07:14:02.314Z] WHERE c.status = @__status_0
[2024-09-06T07:14:02.314Z] Executed DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[@__status_0='?'], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
[2024-09-06T07:14:02.316Z] SELECT count(*)::int
[2024-09-06T07:14:02.317Z] FROM schema1.table1 AS c
[2024-09-06T07:14:02.318Z] WHERE c.status = @__status_0
[2024-09-06T07:14:02.321Z] Executed DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[@__status_0='?'], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
[2024-09-06T07:14:02.322Z] SELECT count(*)::int
[2024-09-06T07:14:02.323Z] FROM schema1.table1 AS c
[2024-09-06T07:14:02.324Z] Executed DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[@__status_0='?'], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
[2024-09-06T07:14:02.324Z] WHERE c.status = @__status_0
[2024-09-06T07:14:02.328Z] SELECT count(*)::int
[2024-09-06T07:14:02.328Z] Executed DbCommand (2ms) [Parameters=[@__status_0='?'], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
[2024-09-06T07:14:02.329Z] FROM schema1.table1 AS c
[2024-09-06T07:14:02.331Z] WHERE c.status = @__status_0
[2024-09-06T07:14:02.331Z] Executed DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[@__status_0='?'], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
[2024-09-06T07:14:02.330Z] SELECT count(*)::int
[2024-09-06T07:14:02.335Z] FROM schema1.table1 AS c
[2024-09-06T07:14:02.334Z] Executed DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[@__status_0='?'], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
[2024-09-06T07:14:02.336Z] WHERE c.status = @__status_0
[2024-09-06T07:14:02.333Z] SELECT count(*)::int
[2024-09-06T07:14:02.337Z] Executed DbCommand (2ms) [Parameters=[@__status_0='?'], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
[2024-09-06T07:14:02.338Z] FROM schema1.table1 AS c
[2024-09-06T07:14:02.340Z] WHERE c.status = @__status_0
[2024-09-06T07:14:02.339Z] SELECT count(*)::int
[2024-09-06T07:14:02.337Z] SELECT count(*)::int
[2024-09-06T07:14:02.342Z] FROM schema1.table1 AS c
[2024-09-06T07:14:02.341Z] FROM schema1.table1 AS c
[2024-09-06T07:14:02.344Z] WHERE c.status = @__status_0
[2024-09-06T07:14:02.344Z] WHERE c.status = @__status_0
[2024-09-06T07:14:02.432Z] Error, Self referencing loop detected for property 'target' with type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1+AsyncStateMachineBox`1[ObjectToReturn,Class1+<GetObjectToReturnAsync>d__2]'. Path 'moveNextAction'.
[2024-09-06T07:14:02.464Z] Title                 : Invalid data processException        : Self referencing loop detected for property 'target' with type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1+AsyncStateMachineBox`1[ObjectToReturn,Class1+<GetObjectToReturnAsync>d__2]'. Path 'moveNextAction'. Inner Exception  :Stack Trace      :    at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.CheckForCircularReference(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonProperty property, JsonContract contract, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)

it seems that the last calls are not executed sequentially.
Why this problem and how can I solve?
sorry for the first poor post. I mistakenly assumed that the information provided might be sufficient

Can you please edit the question and show at least the minimal code for AsyncMethod1 where it performs the database query you mention? It seems possible that the issue might be there not here.

I would assume the methods are executed in the correct order but the printing of the log is not. Depending on the logging framework, log output is often just handed off to a low priority background thread in order to not slow down code execution by logging. The timestamps are the time that line was actually printed, not the time it was enqueued to the logging framework. The console itself uses buffers as well. There are plenty of chances to mix the lines, as evident by the not strictly incremental timestamps.

thanks @LWChris for the claification. and what about the error in the last lines of the log?

@FabioPecoraro That last exception doesn't have anything to do with the code you have shown here. The stack trace says it comes from Newtonsoft.Json when you serialized an object that has some "target" property that references itself or a parent. Think about an object that has a Child property and the child object has a Parent property, or an object that has a MyClass Self { get; } = this; property. You cannot serialize such objects because the circular reference would cause infinite depth.

oh god. @LWChris you're right. I was completely misled by the message because it was the first time I wrote the code in this way with asynchronous calls inside the object initialization. Thank you

I created a fiddle showing that the methods are executed in order as expected: https://dotnetfiddle.net/PC8Xo0.
The output is:
A 
B False
C False
D False
E False
F True
G True
H True
I True

This demonstrates that the async methods are awaited in the order they are written.
The issue you mentioned might be elsewhere in the code.
